# find the negative couple in matrix using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, covariance

I have got a covariance matrix using `dataframe.cov()` in pandas, now i want to find all the most negative couple(eg. `v1` and `v3` is the most negative couple in the matrix because matrix[`v1`, `v3`] is minimum, and then `v1` and `v3` is excluded in the next selection phase) in a ascending order, i want to find all the couple with such character.

here is my matrix:

```
            V1           V2           V3           V4           V5
V1  471.189543   404.059694   -59.847099   415.214121  -571.672083
V2  404.059694  4768.251838  3740.331544   557.050042  1750.542728
V3  -59.847099  3740.331544  6563.713527  -782.229345  3378.108799
V4  415.214121   557.050042  -782.229345  1949.914430  -582.306412
V5 -571.672083  1750.542728  3378.108799  -582.306412  3355.819315
```

Comment: Isn't `cov(V3, V4)` the most negative covariance?

Comment: yes, its a correlation matrix, so (v3, v4) is the most negative couple.

Comment: It looks like a covariance matrix, not a correlation matrix.

Comment: oh, yes, i use the wrong word , i will change it . thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1': [471.18954309999998, 404.05969449999998, -59.847098750000001, 415.21412069999997, -571.67208340000002], 'V2': [404.05969449999998, 4768.2518380000001, 3740.3315439999997, 557.05004150000002, 1750.5427280000001], 'V3': [-59.847098750000001, 3740.3315439999997, 6563.7135269999999, -782.22934510000005, 3378.1087990000001], 'V4': [415.21412069999997, 557.05004150000002, -782.22934510000005, 1949.91443, -582.30641220000007], 'V5': [-571.67208340000002, 1750.5427280000001, 3378.1087990000001, -582.30641220000007, 3355.8193149999997]}, index=['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'])

result = df.stack()
result.name = 'cov'
result = result.reset_index()
result = result.loc[result['level_0'] < result['level_1']]
result = result.sort_values(by='cov')
print(result)
```

yields

```
   level_0 level_1          cov
13      V3      V4  -782.229345
19      V4      V5  -582.306412
4       V1      V5  -571.672083
2       V1      V3   -59.847099
1       V1      V2   404.059694
3       V1      V4   415.214121
8       V2      V4   557.050042
9       V2      V5  1750.542728
14      V3      V5  3378.108799
7       V2      V3  3740.331544
```

The rows are sorted by covariance in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

consider the dataframe `df`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = pd.Index(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'], name='rows')
cols = pd.Index(['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5'], name='cols')

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[  471.189543,   404.059694,   -59.847099,   415.214121,  -571.672083,],
     [  404.059694,  4768.251838,  3740.331544,   557.050042,  1750.542728,],
     [  -59.847099,  3740.331544,  6563.713527,  -782.229345,  3378.108799,],
     [  415.214121,   557.050042,  -782.229345,  1949.91443,   -582.306412,],
     [ -571.672083,  1750.542728,  3378.108799,  -582.306412,  3355.819315,]],
    rows, cols
)
```

---

#### Use `numpy` to find solution more efficiently

Find the row and col of the minimum value.

```
pos = df.values.argmin()
rpos = rows[pos // len(cols)]
cpos = cols[pos % len(rows)]

print rpos, cpos, df.loc[rpos, cpos]

V3 V4 -782.229345
```

---

Sort the entire dataframe

```
ti = np.triu_indices(len(rows), 1, len(cols))
argsorted = df.values[ti[0], ti[1]].argsort()
tups = zip(rows[ti[0][argsorted]], cols[ti[1][argsorted]])

df.stack().loc[tups].rename('cov').reset_index()
```

[image]